# Lattice filter Reflection and Ladder coefficient

Tags: c#, lattice, digital-filter

I am new to discrete filter designing and I would like to design IIR filter using Lattice structure but I have no idea about how can I calculate Ladder and Reflection coefficient.

Little hint or help also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to calculate a 'lattice coefficient matrix' and then iteratively compute the ladder lattice coeficients. See this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85074/how-to-calculate-iir-lattice-filter-coefficients-for-biquad-filter/85084#85084)